# Stream output from external command from inside a powershell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Consider the following command:

```
7z.exe a -t7z folder.7z folder
```

I have the following two stripped down powershell scripts

File 1: common.ps1

```
function Archive-Folder ($src, $dest_path, $archive_name) {

    $script_dir = split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

    if ((test-path $src) -eq $false) {
        write-error "$src is not a valid source directory"
        #return
        return $false
    }

    if ((test-path $dest_path) -eq $false) {
        write-error "$dest_path is not a valid destination directory"
        #return
        return $false
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($archive_name) -eq $true) {
        write-error "$archive_name is not a valid archive name"
        #return
        return $false
    }

    write-verbose "archiving the folder"

    $archive_command = "$script_dir\7z.exe a -t7z $dest_path\$archive_name $src"

    $exe = "$script_dir\7z.exe"
    $arguments = @('a', '-t7z', "$dest_path\$archive_name", "$src")

    iex $archive_command

    # this doesn't stream the output. it prints it all at once.
    # & $exe $arguments | write-verbose

    return $true
}
```

File 2: script.ps1

```
$script_dir = split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. "$script_dir\common.ps1"

$VerbosePreference = "Continue"

$src = 'C:\some\source'
$backup_path = 'C:\some\destination'
$date_format = 'yyyy_MM_dd_HHmm'
$date = get-date
$date_str = $date.tostring($date_format)
$date_ticks = $date.ticks
$archive_name = "backup-$date_str-$date_ticks.7z"

# this prints the output streamed. The output ends with `True`
archive-folder $src $backup_path $archive_name 

# the following however doesn't output anything. in order to separate the command output from my function output, 
# i was printing the command output using write-verbose
$isSuccess = archive-folder $src $backup_path $archive_name
if ($isSuccess -eq $true) {
    #proceed with the rest of the code
}
```

With inputs from @Christian & @zdan, I was able to isolate the issue to the capturing of the return value. Similar to `archive-folder`, I have other functions that execute some commandline tool. I was thinking that each of these functions can return a true or false depending on whether the function was called with the right operations and the commandline tool executed properly.

However, if I capture the return value of my `archive-folder` function, then the output of the command doesn't get printed to the console. Also, my return value doesn't consist of a true or false value. It consists of the entire output of the command.

My first attempt at solving this was to write the command execution statement as `iex $archive_command | write-verbose`, but this did not stream the output.

I suppose I can check for side effects the commandline tool has in case of success (like presence of the archive file) to determine whether my function executed successfully, but am not sure if I will be able to do this for all functions that I may end up creating.

Is there a way to return a value and also stream the output of a commandline tool?

**EDIT 2**

With regards to why am I diving the code into two separate files/functions, my actual use scenario is as follows

> The `script.ps1` will be coordinating this flow. Backup the database (mongodb generates files for each collection of the db). Archive the database backup. Upload the archive to S3. Each of these steps will be done by a separate function in `common.ps1`. The `script.ps1` will only contain the glue code. Posting all this might have complicated the question and I felt wasn't needed to understand the issue am facing

**EDIT 1**

If the folder being compressed has 5 files, 7zip will first output the copyright. Then it will output the text `Scanning`. Then it will output a line `Creating archive at some location`. Then it will process each file, outputting the progress for each file, one by one. This way, we get constant feedback about the progress of the operation.

If I execute the powershell function, then I see no output for the duration of the operation and then all the output at once. I get no feedback from 7zip. I would like to simulate the behaviour that 7zip shows when ran as a standalone exe.

Comment: why do you need the $resp variable?

Comment: @zdan, uncaptured output of any command is added to the output stream. In this function, the output stream is the return value of the function. Without that variable, the value returned to the script that called this function would be an array of strings (in this specific case). That is not what I want. I want to print the output of the `$command` to the screen as it happens.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

`& 7z.exe a -t7z -bsp1 $archive_name $src 2>&1 | Out-Host`

The [`-bsp1`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm) switch redirects the `progress information` stream to the `stdout` stream. This is a feature of 7z. Also look at the [`-bb`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bb.htm) switch.

The `2>&1` redirects the error stream to `stdout`. This is a feature of PowerShell.

> ## -bs (Set output stream for output/error/progress line) switch Syntax
>
> ### Syntax
>
> `-bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2}`
>
> ```
> {id} | Stream Type
> ................................
>  o   | standard output messages
>  e   | error messages
>  p   | progress information
> ```
>
> ```
> {N} | Stream Destination
> ................................
>  0   | disable stream
>  1   | redirect to stdout stream
>  2   | redirect to stderr stream
> ```

Answer (score 0):

why not this way?  If you need

```
function archive-folder ($src, $archive_name) {   
$origcolor = [console]::ForegroundColor
[console]::ForegroundColor = "yellow"
"archiving $src"
$command = "7z.exe a -t7z $archive_name $src"
iex $command    
[console]::ForegroundColor = $origcolor    
}
```

My trivial caller function:

```
Function k
{
  dir c:\ps\ita
  Write-Host "Starting 7zippping from K function"
  archive-folder -archive_name c:\ps\pippo.7z c:\ps\ita
  Write-Host "7zipping from function k ended"
}
```

and what I see in powershell console ( in yellow the output from `archive-folder`)

> k

```
    Directory: C:\ps\ita


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
-a---    08/06/2011    19:26     5,502 MB ita.txt
-a---    28/05/1994    16:59   165,624 KB ITALIANO.A
-a---    28/05/1994    16:54    53,903 KB ITALIANO.B
-a---    28/05/1994    17:00   165,541 KB ITALIANO.C
-a---    08/06/2011    11:06    98,609 KB ITALIANO.D
-a---    28/05/1994    17:00    72,077 KB ITALIANO.E
-a---    28/05/1994    16:54    80,813 KB ITALIANO.F
-a---    28/05/1994    16:55    78,312 KB ITALIANO.G
-a---    28/05/1994    16:55     2,412 KB ITALIANO.H
-a---    08/06/2011    11:07   298,609 KB ITALIANO.I
-a---    28/05/1994    16:55     1,033 KB ITALIANO.J
-a---    28/05/1994    16:55     1,777 KB ITALIANO.K
-a---    28/05/1994    17:01    71,553 KB ITALIANO.L
-a---    08/06/2011    10:59   162,084 KB ITALIANO.M
-a---    28/05/1994    16:56    47,123 KB ITALIANO.N
-a---    28/05/1994    16:56    72,973 KB ITALIANO.O
-a---    08/06/2011    19:37   264,109 KB ITALIANO.P
-a---    28/05/1994    16:56    10,512 KB ITALIANO.Q
-a---    08/06/2011    19:38   327,348 KB ITALIANO.R
-a---    08/06/2011    19:40   566,512 KB ITALIANO.S
-a---    08/06/2011    10:57   184,719 KB ITALIANO.T
-a---    28/05/1994    16:57    19,378 KB ITALIANO.U
-a---    28/05/1994    16:57    61,552 KB ITALIANO.V
-a---    28/05/1994    16:57     1,334 KB ITALIANO.W
-a---    28/05/1994    16:57     1,368 KB ITALIANO.X
-a---    28/05/1994    16:57       533 B  ITALIANO.Y
-a---    28/05/1994    17:01     7,054 KB ITALIANO.Z
Starting 7zippping from K funztion
archiving c:\ps\ita

7-Zip 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03

Scanning

Updating archive c:\ps\pippo.7z

Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.H
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.C
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.F
Compressing  ITA\ita.txt
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.O
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.A
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.B
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.D
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.E
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.G
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.I
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.J
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.K
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.L
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.M
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.N
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.P
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.Q
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.R
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.S
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.T
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.U
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.V
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.W
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.X
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.Y
Compressing  ITA\ITALIANO.Z

Everything is Ok
7zipping from function k ended
```

Comment: When this function is called from another script, the output of this function will be the output of the `iex $command`. The output of $command is NOT automatically written to the console. I can write it to the console AFTER the command has executed, which is what I am doing in my sample code. What I need is for the output of `$command` to stream to the console, ie, get printed to the console in realtime.

Comment: @AmithGeorge I create another ps1 script doing some job then that calling this function then doing other job: I can see the out of script caller and the 7zip output progress in console. I don't understand your need.. sorry.

Comment: could you please modify your answer with the barebones version of the 2 scripts you created.

Comment: @AmithGeorge Added caller function and cut&paste from console

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine. It's still the same issue. Please read the edit I made to my question. I have tried to better explain my issue. The output from 7zip is being printed to the screen all at once, as opposed to being streamed.

Comment: @AmithGeorge Are you sure you are using my two function? In my test I can see 7zip progression % for each file added to the archive as I can see them in a dos shell calling same 7z.exe command.

Comment: True, I was running the script from the ISE. When I ran your code from the console, the output is streaming. Let me re-write my current code to resemble what you have written. Be back in a while.

Comment: @AmithGeorge Yes, in ISE have a different behaviour... the stdout doesn't work in  ISE like in console windows.

Comment: @AmithGeorge Maybe I missing something.. but why you need two function?

Comment: Separation of concerns. The script.ps1 will be coordinating this flow. Backup the database (mongodb generates files for each collection of the db). Archive the database backup. Upload the archive to S3. Each of these steps will be done by a separate function in common.ps1. The script.ps1 will only contain the glue code. Posting all this might have complicated the question and I felt wasn't needed to understand the issue am facing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should be able to just do:

```
&7z.exe a -t7z $archive_name $src | write-verbose
```

Unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: This is a shortened version of what I am doing. On my machine this shows the output AFTER the entire operation has completed. I would like to print each step of the operation as done by 7zip. If you execute that command in powershell, without the `&` and the without the `| write-verbose`, you will see the output being streamed to the console. If the folder has 5 files, it will output `Compressing file 1`, then it will output `Compressing file 2` etc. The code you have posted is outputting the final output. Am I making sense?

Comment: @AmithGeorge I understand what you're saying, but that's not what I am seeing when I try it. I see intermediate output as it goes along compressing.

Comment: Have updated the question. I tried the following from the powershell console: `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"; & 7z.exe a -t7z dummy.7z dummy | write-verbose` . The output didn't stream. It printed all at once. The same command without the `pipe to write-verbose` streams all right.